# How to generate cookies that are normally generated by browser in python

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, http-headers

I'm trying to generate cookies in python, that normally browser generates and then they appear in `request headers` of a http request.

I have a solution of opening `seleniumwire.undetectable.chromedriver` and getting request headers cookies from there but its slow and requires many resources.

Now I am trying to make the same thing but with python `request` library. This is the current code I have, but it only pulls the cookie from response headers.

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()

get =  s.get("https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en")
cookie = get.headers['Set-Cookie']
heder = {
'authority': 'www.sneakersnstuff.com',
'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
'accept-language': 'pl-pl',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'cookie': cookie,
'origin': 'https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/',
'referer': 'https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en',
'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

post = s.post("https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en", headers=heder)
cookiemain = post.headers['Set-Cookie']
print(cookiemain)
```

The cookie I get isn't sufficient and it's missing some values.